# Between two different range numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that has a table for a parameter with two columns: From and To. Both int. It is used for searching scores.
The example of the table is

```
+-----------+-------+----+
| RowNumber | From  | To |
+-----------+-------+----+
|         1 |     0 | 30 |
|         2 |    60 | 80 |
+-----------+-------+----+
```

How can I search a table to have results that include all scores between 0 and 30 and 60 and 80?

I had tried `between` inside a while loop but nothing.

Comment: This is unclear. Please can you provide some sample data and expected results. I've also no idea why you'd need a loop of some kind to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess in the absence of a reply, however, maybe...

```
CREATE TABLE Score (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                    Score int);

INSERT INTO Score
VALUES (65),(17),(97),(14),(34),(79),(37),(87),(65),(63),(15),(75),(05),(25),(38),(28),(88);
GO

CREATE TABLE ScoreRange (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                         [From] int, --Try to avoid keywords, and especially reserved words, for column names
                         [To] int); --Try to avoid keywords, and especially reserved words, for column names
INSERT INTO ScoreRange
VALUES (0,30),
       (60,80);
GO
SELECT *
FROM Score S;

SELECT S.*
FROM Score S
     JOIN ScoreRange SR ON S.Score BETWEEN SR.[From] AND SR.[To];
GO

DROP TABLE Score;
DROP TABLE ScoreRange;
```

Comment: I see your guess is as big as mine :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yep, your answer hadn't loaded yet so I hadn't seen you'd had the same thought. :)

Comment: Yeah, well, you know what they say - twisted minds think alike :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to answer without sample data - but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable As t
JOIN @TVP As p ON t.Score >= p.[From] AND t.Score <= p.[To]
```

Comment: If the ranges overlap this would duplicates some results. I know we don't know whether that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t
where exists (
    select 1 from ranges r
    where t.val between r.from and r.to
);
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.